# Como Mover archivo entre servidores/api mediante HTTP, evitar usar forms

Tags: php, javascript, api, webservice

Hola buenos días tengo una duda tengo un validador de firmas digitales por medio de cargar el archivo en un input file en donde lo envió al api y funciona bien me valida todo, pero habrá una forma de enviar un archivo sin cargarlo a un input file que se envié directamente.

Abajo esta de la manera normal enviando en un file pero se podrá hacerlo directo con la url del pdf o alguna forma distinta.

```
<form name="demo" id="demo" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <table width="100%" align="center" border="1" bordercolor="black" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0">
                <tr>
                    <td>Documento PDF:</td>
                    <td><input type="file" name="uploadFile" size="100" accept="application/pdf" /></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <input type="submit" value="Enviar a validar">
            <div id="prueba"></div>
        </form>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $("#demo").submit(function(event) {
                var parametros = $(this).serialize();              
                var data = new FormData(this);                
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "http://apilocal:8080/rest/service/validate-pdf",
                    data: parametros,
                    cache: false,
                    data: data,
                    processData: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    beforeSend: function(objeto) {
                        $("#prueba").html("enviando...");
                    },
                    success: function(datos) {
                        if (datos.result == '' && datos.status == 'ok') {
                            $("#prueba").html(datos);                           
                        } else if (datos.result == 'VÁLIDO' && datos.status == 'ok') {
                            $("#prueba").html(datos);                          
                        } else {
                            $("#prueba").html('Ocurrio un error en la validación');                           
                        }

                    }
                });
                event.preventDefault();
            });
        </script>
```

Comment: no logro ver cual es la pregunta? puedes formularla mejor?

Comment: Como envio un archivo pdf sin cargarlo a un input file osea algo como enviar la url del archivo

Comment: a ver el archivo donde esta??? en tu escritorio o en el servidor???

Comment: El archivo ya está subido está en servidor

Comment: puedes intentar con esto: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2578128/http-transfer-file-from-server-to-server

Comment: desde php puedes al momento de que se sube el archivo y esta en el disco moverlo a otro servidor consumiendo tambien un php de este otro servidor... solo que tienes que tener cuidado ... con ese php del segundo servidor y tienes que crear algo como un token de autenticacion... para que no suban basura...

Comment: Arriba estoy poniendo de la forma normal de subir archivo, pero lo que necesito es enviar un archivo que esta cargado en el servidor a una api

Comment: y probaste el link que te envie??? o quieres que te lo hagan???

Comment: Investigue mas para usar curl y me salió como quería.

Comment: Perfecto agregalo como respuesta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hola lo solucione con CurlFile enviar el archivo que esta en carpeta compartida en mi red o en mi raiz de mi pc.

```
$apiRest = "http://api.com/service/validate-pdf"; //API
/* CARPETA COMPARTIDA */
$cfile = new CURLFile('\\\\192.168.20.6\\005056-2021.pdf', 'application/pdf', 'miPDF.pdf');

/* EN CASO ESTE EN TU MISMA CARPETA */
$cfile = new CURLFile('C:/xampp/htdocs/005056-2021-1-2.pdf', 'application/pdf', 'miPDF.pdf'); 

// POST ENVIO EL ARCHIVO Y EL NOMBRE QUE PIDE EL API
$pdfData = array('uploadFile' => $cfile);
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $api);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $pdfData); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); 
$response = curl_exec($curl);
var_dump($response);
curl_close($curl);
```